# SDHC card with SPI

Tags: sd-card, spi

I'm working on a Texas Instruments DSP (TMS320F2812).

With my actual soft (C language), I can read information on SD card (<= 2GB). But when I try with a 4GB card, it doesn't works.

I readed a lot of documents, and I know there are many differences between this 2 kind of cards (FAT16, FAT32,...)

But my first problem appears when I send CMD0 ; normally it's :
- 0 1(Start bit) 0 0 0 0 0 0

I attach two pictures :
- The first on when I send CMD0 on a 2GB card
[image: CMD0 on a 2GB card]
- The second one when I send CMD0 on the 4 GB card.
[image: CMD0 on the 4 GB card]

With the same software, the frame is not the same ; do you know where does the problem comes from?

Excuse for my poor English, I'm French.

Regards,

Comment: have you followed an intialization procedure similar to here ? : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77417/what-is-the-correct-command-sequence-for-microsd-card-initialization-in-spi

Comment: Hello pm101, yes of course. I exactly follow the procedure step by step. My software works for <2GB card ;  I just don't understand why the frame sent is not the same between the 2 cards...

Answer (score 0):

I realize something ; problem doesn't comes from CMD0. The 2 cards (2GB & 4GB) accept this command.

Problem comes from the following command, CMD8.
I send CMD8, with arg 0x1AA, but I never have answer 0x1AA. I don't know which answer I received.

Can the low capacity cards (<2GB) accept this command?
CMD0 --> CMD8 -->CMD55 --> ACMD41

Because this is the only way to initialize SDHC card, isn''t it?

Regards,